# Why the method is returning padEnd as undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using the following method, when I am entering `7.0` I get the following error:

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'padEnd' of undefined`

```
formatInput = (value) => {
  const numsAfterDot = 6;
  const isNegative = value < 0;
  const hasDecimals = value.includes(".");
  let absolute = Math.abs(value).toString();
  if (isNaN(absolute)) return;
  else {
    const split = absolute.split(".");
    let start = hasDecimals ? split[0] : absolute.slice(0, 2);
    let rest = hasDecimals ? split[1] : absolute.slice(2, numsAfterDot)
    start = start.padStart(2, "0");
    rest = rest.padEnd(numsAfterDot, "0");
    const result = `${start}.${rest}`;
    return isNegative ? `-${result}` : result;
  }
};
```

Can someone please help me solve this?
[image: error]

**Expected output:**

```
"7.0" should converts to "07.000000"
"12" should converts to "12.000000"
".12" should converts to "00.120000"
"-123" should converts to "-12.300000"
"123456" should converts to "12.345600"
```

Comment: It doesn't say that `padEnd` is undefined, it says that `rest` is `undefined`. Which means that `absolute` did not contain a dot.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the response. I see what you mean. Do you know how can I fix this? Can you please help me out?

Comment: Compute `hasDecimals` on `absolute`, not on `value`.

Comment: I am really unclear what that  `let rest = hasDecimals ? split[1] : absolute.slice(2, numsAfterDot)` is actually supposed to be doing. It makes little sense why you would do the slice if there are no decimals.

Comment: @epascarello just updated my question with the desired output if that helps

Comment: @Bergi - can you please provide snippet of the compute suggestion that you mentioned above? I cannot make it work.

Comment: @dev101 As escaparello said, your slicing is broken as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you test to see if the string you send in has a decimal point.

```
const hasDecimals = value.includes(".");
```

You then convert it to absolute.

```
let absolute = Math.abs(value).toString();
```

When you do that it no longer has a decimal point, so the split is going to be `['7']`

so there is no `split[1]`, hence why it is undefined.

Your code is a bit complicated. I would just split, if it is not a length of 2, I would split the string up into two parts and then pad it.

```js
function custPad (str) {
  // convert to number
  const num = +str;
  // check if negative
  const neg = num < 0 ? '-' : '';
  // get rid of negative, split it at decimal
  const parts = Math.abs(num).toString().split('.');
 
  // if no decimal, than break it up
  if (parts.length === 1) {
    const nums = parts[0];
    // grab first two numbers
    parts[0] = nums.substr(0,2);
    // grab remaining
    parts[1] = nums.substr(2, 6);
  }

  // build the new string with the padding
  return neg + parts[0].padStart(2, '0') + "." + parts[1].padEnd(6, '0').substr(0,6);

}


console.log("7.0", custPad("7.0"))
console.log("7", custPad("7"))
console.log("0.12", custPad("0.12"));
console.log("123", custPad("123"));
console.log("-12", custPad("-12"));
console.log("123456", custPad("123456"));
console.log("12345678911111111", custPad("12345678911111111"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see what you mean. Can you help me fix this scenario?

Comment: Check if absolute has the decimal or check if your split has a length of 2

Comment: Woah @epascarello, thank you so much! Your solution is really great and it worked like a charm compare to what I had. All scenarios looks good except I see two issues. When I enter `12.1234561`, it should convert to `12.123456` which is not happening. The other one is where do I check for `NaN`?

Comment: So put a max length on a substring

Comment: I tried putting the length to substr methods but it did not work out.

Comment: I added substr.

Comment: Thank you very much @epascarello from the bottom of my heart.